# Flutter project Pod install issue in ios side

Tags: cocoapods, flutter-dependencies

I have trying to pod install flutter project in iOS side..but i am unable to install the pod in iOS side

[its error show
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: no implicit conversion of nil into String.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acjSv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed It by deleting the `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock` in ios folder and then run:

```
flutter run
```

or

```
flutter build ios
```

That way flutter will generate the new Podfile for flutter

Comment: Thank you sir for reply. yes i  did it on terminal but some issue generate again

Comment: post your error

Comment: [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: no implicit conversion of nil into String.

 #  from /Users/atpl/Documents/insuranceflutter/ios/Podfile:57
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #      unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path)
 >        FileUtils.cp_r(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.framework'), copied_flutter_dir)
 #      end
 #  -------------------------------------------user18710300